# How long does it take to delete a Google Apps for Domain account and allow recreation?

Tags: google-workspace

Basically, I set up a Google Apps for domain account for one of my clients but upon trying to upload a CSV of users, only half were created and then I kept getting time outs, 404's and other errors which I never saw when setting up another client.

I was not sure how, but thought I may have caused an error or there was an error Google Side when the account was created so I thought it may be best to delete the domain and start from scratch.

Little did I know, you had to wait to recreate the domain!

As far as I can tell from what I have read, there is five days to delete and allow recreation of similar user names, however, I can't see anything that shows how long you have to wait for the domain account.

It has now been 5/6 days and I can't recreate it.

The cancellation email I got shows "...If at any time you would like to sign-up for Google Apps for this or another domain, you can do so by visiting..." But it does not mention how long!!!

I tried emailing Google directly but got no response. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is anywhere from around two days, down to unlimited based on how busy they are.... If you phone or email, they can do it sooner.

For me, it took about 9 days (with one phone call after 8).